# Complex bar chart with data tags

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to create a chart similar to this one that I found online [1](https://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/index2.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.connaissancedesenergies.org%2Ffiche-pedagogique%2Fhydrogene-energie#federation=archive.wikiwix.com&tab=url).
I have no idea if this is even possible using simple tools like tikZ and pgfplots, or if it would be recommanded to simply drop this idea and revert to other processors or simpler tables.
The elements I want to maintain from this example are:

- the labels on the side with the associated value;
- the two stacks side by side so that their respective heights show the correct difference between "production" and "consumption".

I went ahead and added a simple test code with a basic bar chart that I suspect might be the (very) first steps of this process if pgfplots were to be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,%
    ymin=0,%
    ymax=10]
    \addplot coordinates{(1,4.6)};
    \addplot coordinates{(1,2.0)};
    \addplot coordinates{(1,1.6)};
    \addplot coordinates{(2,7.5)};
    \addplot coordinates{(2,0.7)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of the expected outcome (from Hydrogène énergie)]

Comment: Use Tikz. Bars = thick lines. Labels = nodes with option [anchor=east] for the ones on the left side. Arrows: use tikzlibrarry arrows.meta . You should be able to come up at least with the left diagram after skimming through the tutorials inside the pgfmanual (at ctan, or here https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines . // pgfplots adds a frame etc, i.e. things you don't want here.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I didn't think of that! I'll reach out once I'm through with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The bar shape is obtained with the key `ybar`.

The percentages are given by `\WCperc`.

The length, positioning and style of the lines is determined by the keys `lines`, `lines sep`, `lines pos` and `lines style`.

In the bar chart at the right, some texts are moved vertically with the key `data angle shift`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gray]
\sffamily
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  data=\WCvarC{} (\WCperc),
  data sep=0,
  lines=0.5,
  lines sep=0,
  lines style=gray!50,
  ybar={2.5}{7}
}
\wheelchart[
  data pos=0,
  data style=left,
  lines pos=0
]{%
  49/Orange/Vaporeformage du méthane,
  29/teal!10/Oxydation partielle de\\coupes pétrolières,
  18/teal!40/Gazéification de charbon,
  4/teal!70/\'Electrolyse%
}
\node[above] at (1.25,7) {PRODUCTION};
\wheelchart[
  at={(5,0)},
  data angle shift=\WCvarD
]{%
  46/Violet!90/Récupération de pétrole et raffinage/0,
  44/Violet!80/Production d'ammoniac/0,
  4/Violet!70/Production de méthanol/-0.5,
  2/Violet!60/Production et fabrication de métaux/-0.3,
  1/Violet!50/\'Electronique/0,
  1/Violet!40/Industrie alimentaire/0.3,
  1/Violet!30/Autres/0.5%
}
\node[above] at (6.25,7) {CONSOMMATION};
\node[align=center] at (3.75,3.5) {{\huge 50} Mt\\d'hydrogène\\par an\\dans le monde};
\draw[->,>=Triangle] (3.75,4.7)--+(0,2.3);
\draw[->,>=Triangle] (3.75,2.3)--+(0,-2.3);
\node at (0.5,8.5) {\Large\textbf{Hydrogène} Production et consommation dans le monde};
\node at (-3.5,0) {\footnotesize Source: Institution of Mechanical Engineers};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting so much! Thank you, the use is pretty intuitive along with the manual so I was able to finish what I wanted to do.